# Integration tests with Quorum

Tags: java, testing, testcontainers, quorum

I am developing some integration tests (meant to be executed within a dedicated maven goal) for a Java project that relies on [jpmorganchase quorum](https://github.com/jpmorganchase/quorum). The project interacts with several other services each running in its own docker container hence I have been able to replace them in these tests using [testcontainers](https://www.testcontainers.org/), but I am not sure how to do something similar for the quorum. Does anyone know any good solution for this?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [docker container](https://hub.docker.com/r/quorumengineering/quorum) for Quorum. Can you not create your integration tests using that?